# Segmented Control not calling method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble implementing a Segmented Control.  I believe I have everything hooked up, but the method is not being called when I click on either side of the Segmented Control.

Header File

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ServiceConnector.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import "Global.h"

@interface ContactInfo : NSObject

@property char group;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* phoneNumber;
@property int isSelected;

@end

@interface Friends : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ServiceConnectorDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* tblFriends;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* btnAdd;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* btnInvite;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* btnDone;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* contactList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* contactGroup;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* friendList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* modeStr;

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

- (IBAction) InviteClicked;
- (IBAction) AddClicked;
- (IBAction) DoneClicked;
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch;
- (void) sendSMS:(NSString*) phoneNumber;
- (void) sendInviteSMS:(NSMutableArray*) resipients;
- (void) getContacts;
- (void) groupFromContacts;
- (void) groupFromFriends;

// table delegates
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

// service connector delegate
- (void)requestReturnedData:(NSData*)data;

//message delegate
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result;

@end
```

Simplified version of implementation (methods have been removed)

```
    #import "Friends.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"

@interface Friends ()

@end

@implementation ContactInfo

@end

@implementation Friends
@synthesize segmentedControl;




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _friendList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self AddClicked];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [segmentedControl release];
    [_friendList release];
    [_contactList release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)segmentSwitch {
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self AddClicked];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self InviteClicked];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

@end
```

Here is connection inspector for the Segmented Control

[image: Connection Inspector]

Comment: Segment control isnt touch up inside but is value changed

Comment: This is not an Xcode question, but an API usage one. (I'm not interested in the "but I'm using Xcode" argument, because it's invalid.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to hook the control up to the "Value Changed" event, not the "Touch Up Inside" event.

Comment: This worked! It did let me hook up the  "Touch up Inside event", not sure why if it doesn't do anything.  Thank you guys so much, always something little when you're learning.